# How to delete a dimension from aws cloudwatch custom metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Plotted a cloudwatch custim metric using lambda in aws cloudwatch/ but sent wrong dimension. In api call by mistake i sent swapped values for values / dimension name. now i am getting lot of metrics with 0.896, 0.345 etc dimentions. how to delete the. It iss creating garbage in the metric list.see screenshot for details.

[image: metric list screenshot. want to delete those rows]

Comment: What screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

`Dimension` is [part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension) of metric's identity:

> A dimension is a name/value pair that is part of the identity of a metric.

Since its **not possible to delete** any metrics, you [can't remove/change](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/) dimensions of metrics already in the AWS. You have to wait till it expires after 15 months:

> CloudWatch **does not support metric deletion**. Metrics expire based on the retention schedules described above.

For your case, you have to create **new metrics** with correct dimension and use that in your plots and alarms.